# How do I use Clojure memfn with a Java constructor?

Tags: clojure

I want to use a Java constructor as a first-class Clojure function. My use-case is to transform a sequence of strings into a sequence of Java objects that have a constructor with a single string:

Simple Java object:

```
public class Foo {
  public Foo(String aString){
    // initialize the Foo object from aString
  }
}
```

And in Clojure I want to do this:

```
(defn make-foo (memfn Foo. a-string))
(apply make-foo '("one" "two" "shoe"))
```

The apply should return a list of Foo objects created from Strings, but I'm getting this:

```
IllegalArgumentException No matching method found: org.apache.hadoop.io.Text. for class java.lang.String  clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod (Reflector.java:53)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't bother. `memfn` is practically deprecated in favor of the anonymous function literal, with which you can also invoke constructors, e.g., `#(Foo. %)`.

Also, your `apply` call is going to try to invoke `make-foo` once with three string args.  You probably instead want:

```
(map #(Foo. %) ["one" "two" "three"])
```