# Can't refer to Java interop methods when not calling them

Tags: clojure

I'm writing some functions in Clojure to act as helpers. Right now, I'm writing functions that make using Java's random generator easier to use.

Since `random-float` and `random-double` will be nearly identical except for the exact Java function called, I decided to try and factor out the identical parts and use the resulting function:

```
(import '[java.util Random])

(defn- random-floating [f min max ^Random rand-gen]
  (let [r (f rand-gen)
        spread (- max min)
        rand (* spread r)]
    (+ rand min)))

; Errors at ".nextFloat" and ".nextDouble"
(defn random-float [min max ^Random rand-gen]
  (random-floating .nextFloat min max rand-gen)) 

(defn random-double [min max ^Random rand-gen]
  (random-floating .nextDouble min max rand-gen))


(defn random-boolean [rand-gen]
  (.nextBoolean rand-gen))       ; <<--- This works fine
```

The problem is, I'm getting "unresolved symbol" errors at both `.nextFloat` and `.nextDouble`, even though if I call them directly, they're found.

I tried qualifying them (`Random/.nextFloat` and `java.util.Random/.nextFloat`), and neither worked.

Comment: hope this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23118435/usage-of-java-methods-as-a-function-argument-in-clojure

Comment: @OlegTheCat Ahh! Damn. Thanks. Thats such an easy fix. I guess this is a dupe then. I'll accept if you post that.